# How to expire session after 2 hours and also expire when browser closed?

Tags: php, session

I want to expire session after 2 hours and also want to expire session when browser closed

```
add_filter('auth_cookie_expiration', 'my_expiration_filter', 99, 3);
function my_expiration_filter($seconds, $user_id, $remember){
    $expiration = 2*60*60; //UPDATE HERE;
    return $expiration;
}
```

Comment: If you set the expiration to 2 hours, then the expiration is 2 hours. The only way to end a session when the browser is closed is to set the cookie expiration to 0. You can’t do both.

Comment: @JacobPeattie How to expire cookie using wordpress

Answer (score 2):

It is the correct hook. I often also add a bit of javascript, to active the checkboxes inside the form.
In your case it would not be necessary to use the `$accepted_args` parameter – 3 – of the `add_filter()` hook, because you're not using any parameters, and simply work with a return value as integer, in seconds.

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year' ) ) {

    add_filter( 'auth_cookie_expiration', 'keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year' );
    function keep_me_logged_in_for_1_year() {

        return 31556926; // 1 year in seconds
    }

    add_filter( 'login_footer', 'set_default_true_on_checkbox' );
    function set_default_true_on_checkbox() {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById( 'rememberme' ).checked = true;
        document.getElementById( 'wp-submit' ).focus();
        </script>
        <?php
    }

}
```

If you also want to check for a closed browser, then you need a check via javascript, that js should also be added via the hook `login_footer`. See [this how to](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/154801/How-to-end-user-session-when-browser-closed) to learn more about the idea behind it.